# Unity hololens using holotoolkit FOV always 16.97196

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am using unity with holotoolkit for developing app for hololens. The issue is the Field of View (FOV) of the main camera is always 16.97196 no matter what values is input. I even added a script to deliberately set the FOV value to 60 but it resets to 16.97196. Can the FOV value be set the user requirements.

[image: FOV]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual hololens device runs on ~17 FOV, Holotoolkit sets the Camera FOV to ~16.97 to get same output while developing and testing in unity.

As you're developing app for Hololens, there isn't any reason to change FOV and have different output than actual hololens device while testing in unity.

Additionally, you can get the issue details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity/issues/176).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why i want to change FOV because I need to play 360 video in a sphere. The video looks very close and not able to get the desired result. The standard FOV for 360 sphere is 60

Answer (score 0):

You can short the FOV by setting directly another projection matrix to the camera through scripting. For instance, if you need 60 degrees FOV you could write:

```
public class SetCameraProjectionMatrix : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fieldOfViewOverride = 60.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Debug.AssertFormat(cam != null, "No {0} component on game object named {1} as expected.", typeof(Camera), gameObject.name);
        cam.projectionMatrix = Matrix4x4.Perspective(fieldOfViewOverride, cam.aspect, cam.nearClipPlane, cam.farClipPlane);
    }
}
```

Camera.projectonMatrix property documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-projectionMatrix.html

Field of view is then ignored until camera method ResetProjectionMatrix is invoked.

Comment: No it didn't change the FOV.

Comment: The FOV property itself does not change with another projection matrix. Is that it or the frustrum you see that does not change?

Comment: The FOV value remains unchanged, same 16.97